# How to import module in Vue.js project properly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The target is to import module "mint-ui".(https://unpkg.com/mint-ui@2.2.13/)

Logic of my web: Guest will visit my index.html first, and then routed by vue to certain component.

I tried to import it with

```
 <script src="">
```

in my index.html, but in my certain html, when i use some function of mint-ui, it doesn't work.

I tried to 
`import {component} from 'mint-ui' or from 'url' or from 'path/to/js/on/disk'`, the page just doesn't turns out.

How should I import this module?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: read this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mint-ui

Comment: @A.Lau Thank you! But if I don't want to use command line "npm i...", can I import it?

Comment: You cannot import it from a url.

Answer (score 0):

mint-ui doc guide:
https://mint-ui.github.io/docs/#/en2

```
import mint-ui:
<!-- import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mint-ui/lib/style.css">
<!-- import JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mint-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

usage:
<div id="app">
    <mt-button @click="handleClick">Button</mt-button>
</div>
```